# Displaying google map markers from multiple json files

Tags: javascript, php, json, google-maps

I have a database which contains addresses. I wish to display these addresses on a google map. I succeeded in generating a json file like this

```
$json = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" . $row["HUISNUMMER"] . "+" . $row["STRAATNAAM"] . "+" . $row["STAD"] . "&key=MYPRIVATEKEY";
```

I can get the lat and long through php like this (in the same loop where I show the database records):

```
$jsonzip = file_get_contents($json);
$jsondata = json_decode($jsonzip,true);
$jsonlat = $jsondata['results']['0']['geometry']['location']['lat'];
$jsonlong = $jsondata['results']['0']['geometry']['location']['lng'];
```

And now I'm stuck turning these into markers. 
For now I have the default google code to show a marker

```
<script>
  function initMap() {
    var myLatLng = {lat: 50.6847204, lng: 4.1045525};

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 8,
      center: myLatLng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
    });
  }
</script>
```

How would I add all the locations on the map?

Comment: What does the output of the PHP look like (in the HTML served to the browser).  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue (in the question itself).

Answer (score 1):

You will first need to get the PHP variable into the javascript, an example:

```
<?php echo json_encode($jsondata); ?>
```

Then a for loop whith the creaton of a marker inside it. Something like:

```
for(var i = 0; i < jsondata.length; i++){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: jsondata[i]['geometry']['location']['lat'],
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work because there aren't multiple "lat"s inside one json, but multiple json files each with one lat and long :/

Comment: Then you put the code which retrieves the coordinates in a for loop and add them to an array

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
$locations   =   json_decode($jsonzip, true);

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position    :   new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i]['geometry']['location']['lat'], locations[i]['geometry']['location']['lng']),
    map         :   map,
    animation   :   google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    icon        :   new google.maps.MarkerImage( '/PATH/marker.svg', null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(24, 24) ),
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
        infowindow.setContent('<h3>TITLE</h3>');
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
})(marker, i));
}
```

for more informations: https://www.revilodesign.de/blog/google-maps-api/google-maps-api-karte-mit-mehreren-marker-und-infowindow/